# Testing a many to many intermediate model with mock

Tags: django, mocking, many-to-many

I have two tables that are joined through a custom intermediary table:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Bar(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    foos = models.ManyToManyField(Foo, through="FooBar")

class FooBar(models.Model):
    some_attr = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
```

When it comes to testing the save functionality of these models, I'm at a bit of a loss. saving Foo and Bar instances on their own are fine, but how do I test that I can add and save many to many relationships with FooBar using mocking?  Should the many to many addition test happen on the FooBar model or the Bar model? I guess I'm just looking for a bit of direction in testing these kinds of models using mocking rather than fixtures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [factory-boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this, it provides an easy way to set up instances for testing while being far more flexible than using fixtures.

Other options include [model-mommy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/model_mommy) which does a similar thing, and people say the syntax is easier to work with.